# Asus motherboard - which graphics-drivers?

Tags: graphics, asus, downloads, gpu-driver

I've recently purchased an old but working mobo, Asus p5s800-vm/s. The onboard graphics are displaying low-res "safety mode" type graphics on the monitor.

I understand from the guy I bought it from that it will need extra drivers to deliver normal resolution output.

Details:

VGA - Integrated SIS Real 256E Graphics

Chipset SiS 671FX Northbridge SiS 964 Southbridge

CPU - Pentium 4 3GHZ with hyperthreading technology.

So will I need to find drivers for both the SIS Real 256E and the SiS 671FX? Or just one or the other? Does anyone know where I can download these things because there's not much in the way of Linux graphic support on the section of the Asus website for this board.

Thanks for any help you can offer. Before, I've simply installed Ubuntu
on a system and it just worked. Its the first time I've encountered
this situation so I'm a bit bamboozled.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that card has some issues with linux. Have a look at this, it might help you
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.